# python-pip package disappeared in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: upgrade, python, 20.04, pip

I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 LTS. Before upgrading, I had the `python-pip` package installed. But after upgrading, when I try this command the terminal says:

```bsh
$ sudo pip install foo
sudo: pip: command not found
```

I tried to update repository information and install python-pip package, but APT says that there is no package named `python-pip` in the repository.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`python-pip` package is no longer supported by Ubuntu as Python 2.7 is no longer supported. So forget that package. But you can still install it by issuing the following on terminal:

```bsh
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python2 get-pip.py
```

As `python3-pip` package is supported, which provides `pip3` command you can install it Python 3 with apt by:

```bsh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Comment: Another good option is pyenv: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960805/apt-get-install-for-different-python-versions/59268046#59268046